# Tumblr theme... trying to find the type (text, picture, etc) of the first post

Tags: html, css, twitter, tumblr

So I want various aspects of my theme to change depending on the most recent post. Any idea how I could do it?

I would prefer it to be by using on of the tumblr custom {html tag} things, rather than javascript or whatever. Don't know if that's even allowed on tumblr either.

Theme Documents are here:
http://www.tumblr.com/docs/custom_themes

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the first post, in the according type block (block text, block photo, etc..) put custom css that overrides the default style, and you're done

> {block:Post[1-15]} {/block:Post[1-15]}
>     Rendered for the post at the
>   specified offset. This makes it
>   possible to insert an advertisement or
>   design element in the middle of your
>   posts.
>
> Example: {block:Post5}I'm the fifth
>   post!{/block:Post5} will only be
>   rendered on the fifth post being
>   displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You can get your most recent posts as JSON, so you can have a bit of JavaScript which would get the most recent posts then apply some extra CSS magic.